# I have Chromium Queued for Installation and nothing is happening?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I know almost nothing about Linux and now this Ubuntu. My neighbor talks up Linux all the time. I've hinted at asking him to get me going on it. Finally after about 3 years he gave me a USB with Ubuntu Mate. It's doing fine on the old XP. It came with Firefox but I need Chrome, but now I see Chromium is available. I selected it and it reports, Queued for Installation. There is no install button. I feel stupider than normal sitting here waiting for installation to start? I've been on Windows since the first one and before Windows. So what do I do to get this Chromium download started. I tell you the truth all this command line and "get" stuff I do not get, yet. I'm thinking this may be why the neighbor didn't want to start me, I'd been asking infernal questions. Windows is so easy. You download the exe or the zip and it practically installs itself. This Ubuntu, while I like the way it's running on this old XP desktop, is going to take some figuring out and help.

I'd just like to know how to get Chromium installed. AND, is there anyway to save the settings if I pull the USB and go back to the Windows side?

Thanks much!  jack ":-}

Comment: Welcome. We were all beginners once. It's IMPORTANT for you to really internalize that Ubuntu works quite differently from Windows. "Queued for installation" means that there are other installs or removals in line ahead of Chromium. It works one-install-at-a-time, first come, first served. When they are done, Chromium will install...if your USB is not full and if it permits writes.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. So the "other installs" are others I take it? I have asked for nothing but Chromium. There is nothing else to install. I"ll just wait then, it must be queued at a server somewhere. Many thanks!  jack ":-}

Comment: Looking for LIKEs or KUDOs for answers. Still finding my way around this forums conventions.

Comment: No. it's not queued on some server. The apt queue and snap queue are on your local system. Are you in the "Try Ubuntu" environment of the installer? Or did somebody install full Ubuntu onto your USB?

Comment: You haven't told us your release, whether you have Ubuntu-MATE installed, or are running it live (which will mean any installs are lost on shutdown/reboot). Some package managers (eg. Software Boutique as far as I recall; https://ubuntu-mate.org/features/boutique/) use an "Apply" button to install the selected options, https://goinglinux.com/articles/UMSoftwareBoutique_en.htm

Comment: It should be noted that this is not *really* a forum. It's a very specific question and answer platform.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks all! I could rate those answers from "very helpful and friendly" to "what are you doing here?" For a complete newb that has used PC's since the command prompt days I know nothing but all Window's OS. So if this is a forum that is above these types of questions possibly another forum for the unenlightened could be suggested?

I managed to pull my enlightened neighbor over here who has been using Linux family for years. He took note the reason it was not downloading was I was only using the "kick the tires" option and had to install it to get downloads. Once done the download happened. Oh to answer . . .

I have this very old 2005 era Toshiba Notebook Laptop. He helped me install Ubuntu Mate. 18.04.4 LTS I believe I saw somewhere Bionic Beaver? But not sure.

Things that had not worked on 2 factory resets with Windows disk, the wireless adapter to point, are working with this OS. It's a PC dedicated to only one thing and that is a way to remotely work on my Google Docs away from the main PC.

Before I scram with my tail between my legs is there any suggestion for the fastest browser for this older machine. I have Chromium, FF and Vivaldi installed and trying to compare. I only need a lightweight that will insure I can run Google Docs and that's about all. I'll Google if Ubuntu should be defragged now and then. I won't ask that here. :-\

Thanks to all of you. I've joked but I'll move if someone tells me where better to ask these questions.

G'day to all!  jack  ":-}

Comment: FYI:  For a list of places for Ubuntu Support you could visit https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/community-support/709 which lists Ubuntu Forums, and here (Ask Ubuntu) along with others. This site is an SE (Stack Exchange) one that yes is accessible to Ubuntu (and flavor) users via their Ubuntu SSO, but it still operates on SE rules (single question & answer). To download software easily use the Software Boutique found on Ubuntu MATE installs (it's easy & I'm a fan of it).